Did something change in .XCompose processing in the last few months?
I just rebooted my 20.4 system for the first time in over 4 months and the Compose key seemed to be no longer working.
I eventually discovered that now, if I have a personal .XCompose file, the system one is ignored.
So I added an include "%L" line to my ~/.XCompose file, which hasn't changed for a year, and things started working okay again.
(Actually better than okay, some of my private definitions that had previously been ignored now work.)
Did the way this file is processed change recently, and how should I have been aware of it?
